# "Any new projects? Add them to your Stack Overflow CV!" email has a wrong feedback site link

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I just got an email from Stack Overflow Careers:

> [image]

The `feedback site` link links to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). According to [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274213/260841), this was changed to be MSO (here):

> Generally, they do belong on Meta Stack Overflow now

so can this also be updated?

---

Also, could we get an `or` added into:

> Have you changed jobs, written any blog posts, contributed to any open source projects lately?

? It doesn't sound right.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or feature-request...

Comment: A bug is if something isn't working right or as expected.  A feature-request is adding new functionality.

Comment: @JonH so you think this is a feature request?